# My navigation button is not working in mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My navigation button is not working in mobile, please help me. below is code...Thank you in advance.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brajee</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Where's your CSS?

Comment: Not working HOW?

Comment: I count 6 buttons, and not working isn't an issue. Be more specific please.

Comment: .navbar{
  .nav-link{
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:1em !important;
    padding-right: 1em !important;
  }

  .nav-item.active{
    border-left:#444 3px solid;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The reason your hamburger button is not working is because you aren't loading the corresponding JavaScript files and/or jQuery. I'm posting your snippet below with those files and it's working. You can test it by clicking "run code snippet" below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brajee</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navNavbar"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```